# Auto caps on after space within sam text field

Tags: ios, textfield, uppercase, lowercase

I am working with an iOS developer on a reading log app. When a user manually enters the title of a book into a text field, we have it set so that caps are on for the first letter of the first word of the book title. However I'd also like it set so that after the user types the first word of a book title, and taps on the space bar, caps is automatically turned on again for the first letter of each subsequent word in the book's title. Is there a simple way to code this function, or should I save it for an upgrade when I have more money to spend?

Comment: Ha! The upgrade would hopefully include more than this one feature!

Comment: I think I should have said 'update' not 'upgrade', but that is very funny, Marc!

Comment: Sounds pretty challenging to edit the text field settings itself. What would be more plausible would be an interpretation once a search is entered. So... they type in 'the game of thrones', and it shows in the search as 'The Game of Thrones'

Comment: This wouldn't be for a book search, Meshach, but for when the user is entering the book title manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you can set the capitalization setting to "Word" for any given text field directly from the Interface Builder (so no code is even necessary!) or with one line of code if it's being created automatically, if your iOS developer is charging you for this upgrade, then you're being ripped off.

--Edit: The code would be something like the following, if you wanted to know.--

```
[bookTitleField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
```

Comment: I don't think he's ripping me off, but he might not be aware of this setting. Is this in Xcode? I will share this info with him. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kamaros. I will forward this code to my developer.

Comment: @bradfdlad If he wants to do it via the Interface Builder, he can access the setting from the Attributes Inspector for the text field. It's in the same section that allows you to set the autocorrection, keyboard type, appearance, return key type, return key auto-enable, and secure field settings.

Comment: Thanks, I shared your suggestion with my developer and sure enough, it worked! I pass on his thanks too!